# How to set variable to all in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, set, declare

I am still learning SQL and I am wondering if there is any way to set a variable to all instead of any specific value. I would want something like that which is useful for me for testing purposes. I know this is how it works.

```
DECLARE @sku AS VARCHAR(30)
SET @sku = 'ProductA'
```

Is there anyway I can keep the value inside a variable open. Basically something like this.

```
DECLARE @sku AS VARCHAR(30)
SET @sku = '%'
```

or

```
DECLARE @sku AS VARCHAR(30)
SET @sku LIKE '%'
```

I am not exactly sure how it works in variables. I tried finding it but couldn't find something that fulfills my purpose. Basically I keep changing the values for the variables between specific value to %. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Added:**

```
DECLARE @sku AS VARCHAR(30) = '%'
DECLARE @name AS VARCHAR(40) = '%'

select * from table1 
where sku = @sku 


select * from table2 
where sku = @sku 


select * from table3 
where name = @name
```

Basically in the above sample query, I have to commenting and uncommenting the where clause in 3 different tables. There is a situation where I put value in @sku on the top and I can use the where clause in the select statements. For testing purposes, I have to comment the where statements but for that I need to do that in 3 different queries. Is there anyway if I can just put the filter on the top instead of commenting all 3 where clauses. Does it make sense?

Comment: How would you want to use this ?

Comment: What's your end goal?  Are you trying to do something like a Begins With or Ends With match based on a variable value?

Comment: Basically my goal is, to set a variable to % where it shows all the variables. The way it works in where clause. For example, where sku like '%'. Can I do something like this in a variable?

Comment: What do you mean "show all the variables? As a `SELECT` returns all the variables you've `DECLARE`Dd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal to use an optional "all"-value for a parameter, you can do it like this:

```
DECLARE @sku nvarchar(100) = '%'; -- or any other token

...
WHERE @sku IN (field, '%')
```

This evaluates to: if @sku is `%`, the condition is always true and returns all rows.
For any other value, it only filters the rows where `field` equals the parameter.

Comment: Perfect. This worked like a charm. Anyway we can do the something with integer? Do I have to convert both @sku and field to integer first ?

Comment: Actually I got it. All I needed to do is convert both to NVARCHAR. Thanks again @KekuSemau for your time and help. Appreciate it.